# Using <ahref> tag in google sheet GUI using google script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am creating a GUI using google sheets and google script. As of recently, that requires serving HTML with the GS code.

I have a google sheet, that, when opened, provides a pop-up for users to view some data. I have a script that within the html file that I would like to link to an external page. For example, consider this line of code in a text

```
document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google!</a>';
```

In the small GUI window that is provided, if I left click the link, the GUI goes blank (white), and nothing else seems to happen.  However, if I right click and open the link in a new page, it works fine.

Here is my question: 
Why can I not left click to open the link?

Side question (I can post this separate if it is better etiquette on this site): Is there a way to increase the size of the GUI window provided by my google script? Or perhaps even open up the data in a new page with the html?

update: Stub for serving the html:

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('TeacherView')
     .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(html);

}
```

Thanks,

Jordan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the target="_blank" tag in the `<a>`.

Insteado of using show, use [showModalDialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)) or [showModelessDialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModelessDialog(Object,String)).

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm. I can accept your answer in 5 minutes (according to stackoverflow).   As for the second part, I am not sure what a Stub is (I am not really a software dev, just some guy who said he could make things run more smoothly), but here is my code to serve the gui in google script:   function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('TeacherView')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(html);

}

Comment: That is a stub, updating original answer with method that alows resizing.

Comment: Got it, I updated the post above. Please let me know if I should include more code or perhaps make a new question?